# Is it possible to open 2000 streaming connections by impersonating 2000 mailboxes?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am in the process of creating an Exchange Service account to listen for EWS notifications for up to 2000 mailboxes. I have been reading through the documentation and it states that

> Sa1 can open the connection in the following ways:.... By
>   impersonating any of the users — m1 for example — so that the
>   connection is charged against a copy of m1’s budget. (M1 itself can
>   open ten connections by using Exchange Online, and all service
>   accounts impersonating m1 can open ten connections by using the copied
>   budget.)
>
> If the connection limit is hit, the following workarounds are
>   available: If option 1 is used, the administrator can create multiple service accounts to impersonate additional users.

The microsoft documentation is here: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Can someone tell me if it is possible to open up 2000 streaming connections to EWS using the same service account by impersonating 2000 mailboxes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Can someone tell me if it is possible to open up 2000 streaming connections to EWS using the same service account by impersonating 2000 mailboxes?

Yes I have apps that work with 3000+ users but it can be environment dependant. As the link you posted suggests that you should be using Grouping to maintain affinity in 2013 and greater. There is a maximum of 200 user per group (which basically means per connection). The concurrent connection charge if your using Grouping and Impersonation should be charged to the Mailbox your Anchoring the Group connection to (which is generally the first user in the group) not the service account. As each group should have a different anchor Mailbox you shouldn't run into any problems with the 10 User concurrent connection limit.

If you are using Exchange Online you'll find your users are spread across a large number of Servers and most probably data-centres so as long you implement grouping and impersonation correctly you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately we have a scenario where we have potentially up to 2000 different devices connecting using the same service account, in which case I don't think grouping is appropriate. This is an extreme scenario, but one we need to account for. Is this scenario going to work?

Comment: It relatively simple then if you use impersonation then the charge is to the impersonating mailbox not the service account. If you don't then the charge is to the service account and your going to be limited to 10 simultaneous connections unless you modify the throttling policy that applies to that service account which shouldn't be a problem if its OnPrem.

Comment: From what you are saying it sounds like it is going to be possible to do what we want as long as we use impersonatation. I had been informed that the HangingConnectionLimit would kick in long before we had created 2000 streaming connections. Have you had any issues with the HangingConnectionLimit value? Details on this limit seem pretty scarce on the internet from what I can find.

Comment: The HangingConnectionLimit will only affect you if you don't use impersonation. If you use Impersonation then the charge is against the impersonating account.

Comment: Thanks, very useful.